# Hide div, without hiding it's nested divs

Tags: jquery

This is a simple question, but i can't seem to find the answer anywhere on stackoverflow.

I have the following code-snippet:

```
<div>//The div to be hidden
    <div></div>//I don't want to hide this div
    <div></div>//Nor this one
</div>
```

The reason why i wanna do this is because, when i hide the divs, i hide them using their tagname, but when i show them, i use their classname. Therefore the innerdivs or the "nested divs" doesn't show up again.

## EX:

Before:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

After:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;"></div>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not hide a parent element and keep it's children visible

Comment: Do you have example code (html with example content, and any js/css you have) and a description of what is meant to happen?

Comment: i don't want the children to be visible on the page, i just don't want them to be hidden.

Comment: Just added a snippet of what i want it to look like. if i do ´$("div").hide()´ it will just hide all the divs. i only want the parent div to hide, and keep the rest unhidden, and yes i know they still won't show up on the page.

Comment: Is there an element containing several of these?

Comment: Why not use the same class to hide them, this seems like a self inflicted problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the code provided is inside another element. I'm going to call this `div#root`

```
<div id="root">
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To hide all immediate `div` children of `#root`, you can use the selector `#root > div`.

So, your jQuery might look like `$('#root > div').hide()`

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: That did it, and very easily too!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
$( "div:first" ).hide();
```

That will hide just the first div on the page. But anyway I would suggest to use the class or id...

So if you have more of them you should basically check wether their parent element is div, if it is, then don't hide them, otherwise hide. So...

```
            $('div').each(function(){
                _this = $(this);
                if(!_this.parent().is("div")){
                    _this.hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ohh, i can't use this one, as i have more than one div to hide. bah, i should have said that in the question. sorry >.>