# v-if on a DIV but always display its contents with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

With Vue.js I need to toggle a parent-div, but ***always*** show the child-div.

```html
<div v-if="showparent" class="parent">
  <div class="child"> 
    Child should always be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as I know this is not possible with Vue.js.  The `v-if` directive removes all div's inside when `showparent` is false.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733654/hide-div-without-hiding-its-nested-divs

Comment: No it's not. Doing this with jQuery is entirely different from doing this with Vue.js

Comment: What you do it with is beside the point, you can't have the child of a hidden element visible... it's just not possible with HTML and CSS,

Comment: The whole point of Vue.js and `v-if` is that it doesn't *hide* the element, but removes it entirely from the DOM. I just don't want the child elements removed too. There should be a separate directive for this, in my opinion, which is why I asked if someone ever did this.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a v-else and add your child in it. creating a component for child would save code repeatation as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional parent element in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886148/optional-parent-element-in-vue-js)

Comment: add the child div into v-else

Comment: @str You got it the wrong way around, the question you posted is older than this one (but did attract a bit more attention), also it's your question ;)

Answer (score 6):

I have found two ways to do what you want to achieve, first one is to just repeat the child code in a v-else (not optimal because you need to repeat the code.., but you could wrap the content in a component) :

```html
<div v-if="showparent" class="parent">
  <div class="child"> 
    Child should always be visible
  </div>
</div>
<div v-else class="child">
    Child should always be visible
</div>
```

---

Or you can create a custom component:

Vue 2 using a render function

```js
export default {
    name: "v-if-parent",
    props: {
        condition: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        },
        fallbackWrap: {
            type: String,
            default: 'div'
        }
    },
    render(el) {
        if (this.condition) {
            let parent = this.$scopedSlots.parent()[0];
            if (typeof this.$scopedSlots.default === 'function')
                parent.children = this.$scopedSlots.default();
            return parent;
        } else if (typeof this.$scopedSlots.default === 'function') {
            let children = this.$scopedSlots.default();
            if (children.length > 1) {
                //We can only return a single vnode in vue 2 so if multiple children, wrap them in a div
                return el(this.fallbackWrap, null, children)
            }
            return children[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage

```html
<v-if-parent :condition="showparent" fallback-wrap="span">
  <template #parent><a href="somelink" /></template>
  This text is always visible <span>You can include absolutely whatever you want in the default slot</span>
</v-if-parent>
```

[image: Try the Vue 2 Template]

Vue 3 using Teleport

```vue
<template>
  <slot v-if="condition" name="parent" :ref="(el) => (telRef = el)"
    ><slot></slot
  ></slot>
  <Teleport v-if="condition && telRef" :to="telRef"><slot></slot></Teleport>
  <slot v-else></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

defineProps({
  condition: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
});

const telRef = ref(null);
</script>
```

Usage

```html
<v-if-parent :condition="showparent" fallback-wrap="span">
  <template #parent="{ref}"><a href="somelink" :ref="ref" /></template>
  This text is always visible <span>You can include absolutely whatever you want in the default slot</span>
</v-if-parent>
```

[image: Try the Vue 3 Template]

Comment: Pretty sure you will break interpolation and reactivity with this approach.

Comment: I changed the vue directive for a component, it works better, the vue directive had problems in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a div hides all contained (child) divs. Move the parent out into a container div, do not nest the child div in it.

Comment: With Vue.js you can conditionally include elements in the HTML using directives. I want to use this condtion only on the wrapping element, but not on its contents. Quite valid question if you ask me.

Comment: Did someone say it wasn't a valid question? Doesn't change the way Javascript and CSS work. I posted the reason it doesn't work, a solution, and a link to a duplicate question. HTH (I'm not the one who down voted your question if that is what you are assuming.)

Answer (score 0):

I made the following component. It doesn't seem perfect as it requires to also define parent of the potential wrapper element and both types and properties are passed as 'props' instead of using pure HTML, but it should work.

```html
<template>
  <div :is="mainElementType"
    v-bind="mainElementProperties">
    <div v-if="wrapperElementType"
      :is="wrapperElementType"
      v-bind="wrapperElementProperties"
      class="wrapper-element">
      <slot/>
    </div>
    <slot v-else/>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      mainElementType: {
        default: 'div'
      },
      mainElementProperties: Object,
      wrapperElementType: String,
      wrapperElementProperties: String
    }
  }
</script>
```

Usage example below.

```html
<optional-wrapper main-element-type="h2"
  :wrapper-element-type="displayWrapperElement && 'span'">
  <span class="wrapped">WRAPPED</span>
</optional-wrapper>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found one case that if you write incorrect , `v-if` will not take effect.
e.g.

```
<table>
   <tr v-if='....'>
      <tr>
          <td> I will be always visible! </td>
      </tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```