# Optional parent element in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to define the parent element as optional based on a condition but always show its children in Vue.js?

For example:

```
<a :href="link">Some text</a>
```

What I would like to achieve is the following DOM depending on `link`

```
<a href="somelink">Some text</a> <!-- when link is truthy -->
Some text                        <!-- when link is falsy -->
```

**Potential solutions**

- Duplicate the children:

  ```
  <a :href="link" v-if="link">Some text</a>
  <template v-if="!link">Some text</template>
  ```

  But that is not a good solution especially as there might be more content than just a simple text.
- Write my own component that does the logic depending on some attribute. But this seems overkill and also has to be flexible enough for different kind of element types or attributes.

As I don't like either of these approaches, I wonder whether there is no simpler solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you addressed all options and a component sounds the best one for me.

Comment: @JonatasWalker There is a third option using a custom directive. However, this does not really work with reactivity as after unwrapping, you might have to re-wrap the children again. So far, I was not able to make this work correctly.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959224/v-if-on-a-div-but-always-display-its-contents-with-vue-js/56185035#56185035

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After some more digging, I found a way that works and is actually very simple. It uses the [`is` special attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) that is actually meant to be used when you cannot bind components to HTML elements directly.

```
<a :href="link" :is="link ? 'a' : 'span'">Some text</a>
```

This will result in either of the following:

```
<a href="somelink">Some text</a> <!-- when link is truthy -->
<span>Some text</span>           <!-- when link is falsy -->
```

Comment: You can also look into a render functions. `render (createElement) { return createElement(this.link ? 'a' : 'span', {...}, this.$slots.default) }` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: Like it. You really dug.

Comment: I like it, thank You. I think I will not use it though as for now setting `'template'` as `is` doesn't work as I would like it to.

Answer (score 6):

For Vue 3, the following will do:

```html
<!-- `v-fragment` is globally registered -->
<component
  :is="condition ? 'custom-component' : 'v-fragment'"
  custom-component-prop
  ...
>
  ...
</component>
```

```html
// v-fragment.vue
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
  }
</script>
```

For Vue 2, a workaround is to do:

```html
<component
  :is="condition ? 'custom-component' : 'div'"
  custom-component-prop
  ...
>
  ...
</component>
```

The tradeoff is that an extra element like `div`/`span` will be rendered since Vue 2 doesn't support fragments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of custom components and [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots) to alleviate duplication of children, for example:

```
<custom-component>
    <a :href="link" slot="slot-name-here" v-if="link">
        <custom-content-component></custom-content-component>
    </a>
    <div slot="slot-name-here" v-else>
        <custom-content-component></custom-content-component>
    </div>
</custom-component>
```

Or if the content you want to change is not too complex maybe you could look into using [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)

Comment: This is actually what I meant with "write my own component". Yes this works, but if I want to add attributes to the link (e.g. `class`, `target`, ...) it gets messy.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Not sure why my previous answer was deleted.</del> Turns out you can't just C&P answers across multiple Qs. I've gone ahead and flagged the other Qs as dups of this one (I'm trying here... come on moderators...)

---

I've run into this exact issue several times myself and decided to go ahead and create a module with the solution I've been using locally, which can find on NPM:

[vue-wrapped-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-wrapped-component)

This module provides a functional Vue component that allows any component or element to be conditionally wrapped using another component or element.

The previous answers semi-work for very basic of circumstances. This module provides a more robust solution that works in almost any situation, especially complex ones where there's a risk of duplicating lots of code just because you need a simple conditional wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component to make what you want to achieve:

Vue 3 is much better at handling this, because you are not limited to one element at the root template and you can use the native Teleport component

```vue
<template>
  <slot v-if="condition" name="parent" :ref="(el) => (telRef = el)"
    ><slot></slot
  ></slot>
  <Teleport v-if="condition && telRef" :to="telRef"><slot></slot></Teleport>
  <slot v-else></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

defineProps({
  condition: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
});

const telRef = ref(null);
</script>
```

Usage

```html
<v-if-parent :condition="showparent" fallback-wrap="span">
  <template #parent="{ref}"><a href="somelink" :ref="ref" /></template>
  This text is always visible <span>You can include absolutely whatever you want in the default slot</span>
</v-if-parent>
```

[image: Try the Vue 3 Template]

Vue 2 using a render function, it has a few quirks you can't really get around (eg: a wrapper around the children if it contains multiple elements)

```js
export default {
    name: "v-if-parent",
    props: {
        condition: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        },
        fallbackWrap: {
            type: String,
            default: 'div'
        }
    },
    render(el) {
        if (this.condition) {
            let parent = this.$scopedSlots.parent()[0];
            if (typeof this.$scopedSlots.default === 'function')
                parent.children = this.$scopedSlots.default();
            return parent;
        } else if (typeof this.$scopedSlots.default === 'function') {
            let children = this.$scopedSlots.default();
            if (children.length > 1) {
                //We can only return a single vnode in vue 2 so if multiple children, wrap them in a div
                return el(this.fallbackWrap, null, children)
            }
            return children[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage

```html
<v-if-parent :condition="showparent" fallback-wrap="span">
  <template #parent><a href="somelink" /></template>
  This text is always visible <span>You can include absolutely whatever you want in the default slot</span>
</v-if-parent>
```

[image: Try the Vue 2 Template]