# Conditionally rendering parent element, keep inner html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any built-in way to go about conditionally showing a parent element?

To illustrate:

```
<a v-show-but-keep-inner="someCondition">
    <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
</a
```

Comment: see if slots can help you achieve what you are looking for. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional parent element in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886148/optional-parent-element-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a job for custom directive. I made this one as a quick POC:

```js
Vue.directive('showButKeepInner', {
  bind(el, bindings) {
    bindings.def.wrap = function(el) {
      // Find all next siblings with data-moved and move back into el
      while (el.nextElementSibling && el.nextElementSibling.dataset.moved) {
        el.appendChild(el.nextElementSibling).removeAttribute('data-moved')
      }
      el.hidden = false
    }

    bindings.def.unwrap = function(el) {
      // Move all children of el outside and mark them with data-moved attr
      Array.from(el.children).forEach(child => {
        el.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', child).setAttribute('data-moved', true)
      })
      el.hidden = true
    }
  },

  inserted(el, bindings) {
    bindings.def[bindings.value ? 'wrap' : 'unwrap'](el)
  },

  update(el, bindings) {
    bindings.def[bindings.value ? 'wrap' : 'unwrap'](el)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    someCondition: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <button v-on:click="someCondition = !someCondition">{{ someCondition }}</button>
  </p>
  <a v-show-but-keep-inner="someCondition" href="/">
    <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice directive, but it doesn't account for the top element containing any text nodes. It only moves elements.

Comment: @BunsofAluminum indeed because it uses `el.children`. I think using `el.childNode` it should account text nodes too.

Answer (score 8):

For Vue v3.x, the following would work:

```html
<!-- `v-fragment` is globally registered -->
<component
  :is="condition ? 'custom-component' : 'v-fragment'"
  custom-component-prop
  ...
>
  ...
</component>
```

```html
// VFragment.vue
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
  }
</script>
```

For Vue v2.x, a workaround is to do:

```html
<component
  :is="condition ? 'custom-component' : 'div'"
  custom-component-prop
  ...
>
  ...
</component>
```

The tradeoff is that an extra element like `div` will be rendered since Vue v2.x doesn't support fragments.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same Problem.

Vue.js Core team member [LinusBorg](https://forum.vuejs.org/u/linusborg) provides a great solution for this use case using a functional component with a custom render function:

```js
Vue.component('with-root', {
  functional: true,
  props: ['show'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    const children = ctx.children.filter(vnode => vnode.tag) // remove unnecessary text nodes
    // console.log(children)
    if (children.length !== 1) {
      console.warn('this component accepts only one root node in its slot')
    }
    if (ctx.props.show) {
      return children[0]
    } else {
      return children[0].children
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <with-root v-bind:show="show">
    <a href="#">
      <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
    </a>
  </with-root>
  <br>
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <pre>{{$data}}</pre>
</div>
```

His fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/w9d8ujn8/

Source:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/conditionally-render-parent-element/9324/2

Answer (score 4):

If someone happens to be using the **vue-fragment** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment) library, the following works:

```
<component :is="someCondition ? 'a' : 'fragment'">
   <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
</component>
```

That being said, I do not recommend to use one library just to do this. But if you already do, it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Without Vuejs or other framework context, solely DOM.
You can't remove a DOM element without removing its children too.
What you could do is get the children of a DOM element and replace them with the parent or something similar like that.
With Vuejs you may be able to hide this functionality behind a directive or component, but I think this would be overcomplicating what you want to achieve.

If you want your anchor not to be clickable in certain cases, you could do something like `v-on:click.prevent="yourCondition && xxx()"`. On top of that you could use css classes to hide the fact that it's still an anchor `v-bind:class="{ fakeAnchor: yourCondition}"`.

Though the simplest solution may be to just duplicate your html.

```
<a v-show="someCondition">
    <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
</a>
<span v-show="!someCondition">This is always rendered no matter what</span>
```

The best solution depends on what your case is. If the real inner content will be much larger it might not be okay to duplicate that. If that's the case you could encapsulate that in another vue component.

Comment: It's large enough to get messy if duplicated. It also has different styles for when it's wrapped in a `<a>` element and it might be even more complicated to change that at this point. How would such directive look like?

Comment: Maybe you'll be better off using the render function. In that case you could capture the children in a variable and wrap it with an anchor using js.

Comment: A directive will be messy too. Try to wrap your complicated html in another component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach helps you (using 'is'):

```
<template lang="pug">
  component(is=someCondition?"v-show-but-keep-inner":"my-another-component")
    v-form
      v-layout
        v-flex
          v-btn(@click="doThat")
</template>
```

This way parent component changes depending on 'someCondition' and children are the same for both conditions.