# v-if for surrounding element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Let's say I have the following case

```
<div class="entry">
  <img src="image1.png">
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <a href="#mylink">
    <img src="image2.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Now, items needs to be iterated, using  depending on a condition:

```
<div class="entry" v-for="o in items">
  <a :href="o.url" v-if="o.url != ''">
    <img :src="o.image">
  </a>
  <img :src="o.image" v-else>
</div>
```

With `items = [{url: '', image: 'image1.png'}, {url: '#mylink', image: 'image2.png'}]` this will correctly render to the same snippet from above:

```
<div class="entry">
  <img src="image1.png">
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <a href="#mylink">
    <img src="image2.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

But as you can see, I'm copy-pasting the `<img>` tag for the `v-if` directive. In this case I guess it's simple enough, but I want to know if there a more DRY approach.

I'm looking for something like:

```
<div class="entry" v-for="o in items">
  <a :href="o.url" v-if-always-render-children="o.url != ''">
    <img :src="o.image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Which should render to the same snippet. Of course the directive `v-if-always-render-children` doesn't exists.

How to avoid declaring the `<img>` tag (and possible children tags) more than once?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this and `v-else` is fine.

Comment: I agree that v-else is fine, but this custom directive will essentially do what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299828/4497544

Answer (score 0):

`v-else` is fine, if you're really concerned about it and are worried about the size of the content, then make that content a component.

alternatively you can use render functions or jsx, but unless this thing gets quite a bit more complex, `v-else` is just fine