# Vue reactively removing redundant tags

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I wonder if there's a easy way to remove redundant tags, and if it's worth effort to do it. For example i have a div that groups me childrens in row:

```
<div :class="multipleChildrens ? 'row' : ''">
```

But when there's only one child i dont need div no more. I thought you could use a template tag for it with combination of component tag, but it seem doesn't work this way.

```
<component
    :is="multipleChildrens ? 'div' : 'template'"
    :class="multipleChildrens ? 'row' : ''"
>
```

How can i deal with it another way, or maybe it doesn't have a sense to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just use `v-if` and `else`? What you want is doable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293401/conditionally-rendering-parent-element-keep-inner-html But why?

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for.