# Outside elements with if condition, inside element always exist (Vue.js)

Tags: html, vue.js

I have one question. Is it any simple way to make class 'a' elements with if condition, class 'b' element always exist.

```
<div v-if="aaa===1" class='a'>
  <div class='b'></div>
</div>
```

or i have to write two times.

```
<div v-if="aaa===1" class='a'>
  <div class='b'></div>
</div>
<div v-else class ='b'></div>
```

i think writing two is really redundant

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally rendering parent element, keep inner html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293401/conditionally-rendering-parent-element-keep-inner-html)

Comment: I would find the second one a lot more readable especially when you consider a new developer coming into your codebase, they might not know that there is some magic going on to render this inner element. There are solutions posted in the comments here to address your issue, but I would prefer to not do those unless there is a really good reason.