# How to use Vue's Dynamic Component with a Fragment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Is it possible to use Vue's `<component>` to conditionally render a component or *nothing* instead?

For instance, consider the following pattern:

```
<component :is="hasTooltip ? 'CustomTooltip' : 'div'">
  <div>Hover over me!</div>
</component>
```

In this case, we are rendering a `CustomTooltip` component when the `hasTooltip` value is true, otherwise we are rendering a normal div. Is it possible to render a fragment in place of this div( like the `<>` fragment in React) that will get stripped out in the browser? How might this be accomplished? I'm on Vue 2.0.

Conditionally rendering the component won't work because we want the "Hover over me!" text to render regardless.

Comment: Does `<Toolpit @mouseover="showMessage" @mouseleave="hideMessage"/>` not work here?

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to conditionally wrap this "Hover over me" div with the CustomTooltip. The CustomTooltip component has a lot going on, it actually expects some slot props and so forth, so not really.

Comment: If I used v-if then the "Hover over me" div would disappear, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a conditional tooltip--which is what I've got above--except that ideally I wouldn't have to render a div when that condition is false.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but aren't you just looking for the vue-fragment plugin? there's a vue2 port for the main vue-fragment plugin, more here: https://bestofvue.com/repo/privatenumber-vue-frag-vuejs-utilities

Comment: I really doubt about the "nothing" part. If `<component>` does not render at all, it's content (slot) will not render either.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43293401/381282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```js
Vue.component('tooltip', {
  template: `<div> Tooltip for: <slot></slot> </div>`
})

Vue.component('wrap-if', {
  functional: true,
  props: ['wrap', 'wrapper'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    
    if (ctx.props.wrap) {
      return h(ctx.props.wrapper, ctx.data, ctx.children)
    } else {
      // maybe check that children.length === 1 as Vue 2 does not support fragments
      return ctx.children
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    wrap: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <wrap-if :wrap="wrap" wrapper="tooltip">
      <span>This is always rendered no matter what</span>
  </wrap-if>
  <br>
  <button @click="wrap = !wrap">Toggle</button>
  <pre>{{$data}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This is super interesting, thank you! Will mark as the correct answer since this is for vanilla Vue-2, although long-term will probably use the plugin or upgrade in order to use fragments, as it's simpler and we don't often use the render pattern. Thank you!

Comment: If the wrapper component is not variable (and it's not in OP's code), this can be safely written as `template: '<CustomTooltip v-if="condition"><slot /></CustomTooltip><slot v-else />'`, correct? The main point is you're delegating the render decision to a separate component, taking slot contents, + condition as prop. Does this keep the same node? Say I go in, make border red and then change the condition. Do I lose the red border?

Comment: @a.h.g. Yes, that could work but not in Vue2 as the template compiler will tell you you have multiple root nodes I guess. I'm not sure I follow the rest of your question...

Comment: To my knowledge you can have multiple root nodes in Vue2's root if they have `v-if`/`v-else`. I'm not sure if one of them can be `<slot />`, though. As to the second question, I already checked it. I was asking if the rendered node (the slot) remains the same when the condition is changed. The answer is *"no"*. When using `portal-vue`, for example, the rendered DOM element remains the same instance/element and it's appended to the other place in DOM, based on condition value.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right with `v-if`/`v-else`. Not sure about `slot` as root but sounds familiar - I'm not using Vue 2 much lately. I understood but missing the details. Why is it important whether it is the same node or not? Only situation where it could be an issue is if you are manipulating the DOM directly, which is bad idea in Vue anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not important, it's just something I wondered whether possible, given the question. It could become important if the slot contents are stateful or particularly heavy (e.g: a mapbox instance). Clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Just consolidating some other comments on this into an answer.

It appears that there's no clean way of conditionally wrapping a component without a plugin in Vue-2, because fragments are not available.

However, this same pattern can be accomplished with either a Vue-2 fragment plugin, or in Vue3, with the use of the `fragment` component, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65803763/7860026) answer. Instead of rendering the div, render the fragment.

Comment: The plugin mentioned in my answer is incredibly light and written by a core Vue team member. The only difference between that plugin and whatever answers you might get here is that the plugin has been thoroughly tested in all browsers.